# Trigger a 404 error with CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, http-status-code-404

I've been reading [CakePHP's 2.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html?highlight=migration) where it's stated that `cakeError()` has been removed because it was used for exceptions. It's a really weird change IMHO because I used it to block access to unauthorized users or to trigger an error when the paginated items exceeded the total, and things like that.

And now what? Should I just throw a `die()` or a redirect? I really want to let know the users that something was not found and Cake used to provie a stright way to do so... now it doesn't.

Any thoughts/hacks/workarounds about it? Thanks, happy holidays!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to throw the corresponding exception, in your case the `NotFoundException`:

```
throw new NotFoundException();
```

See also the chapter about [exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) in the cook book.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the built-in exceptions. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') == 'P' || $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') == 'U') {
            //die('you are not allowed to access this page');
            //throw new ForbiddenException;
            throw new NotFoundException('404 Error - Page not found');
        }
```